# What does zitch dog mean?

Tags: is-it-a-word

In "How I met your mother" they played a road game called "zitch did" (or possibly "zitchdog"). Is there such a word as "zitch" (or possibly "zitchdog")?

Comment: Hello, NPS. What does your research show?

Comment: I tried googling it but found only HIMYM references.

Comment: Some would say it's a word because it's been used, but thankfully OED has rather more sensible tests candidates have to pass.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car_game

Answer (score 4):

[Zitch dog](http://folklore.usc.edu/?p=11703):

Basically, the point of the game is if you see a dog, you have to be the first person to say, “Zitch Dog!” and then you get a point. Person with the highest score by the end of the car ride gets free dinner.

Comment: Sounds like a mix between 'shotgun' and pub cricket.

Comment: The link provided gives some information but in general your post doesn't answer my question. Is there such a word as "zitch"? Does it mean anything?

Comment: @NPS - I would guess that "zitch" is a play on "ditch".